# Generating PNG images from Kinect data

Tags: kinect, image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a complete beginner at ROS and I am using a Turtlebot SDK. All I want to do is generate PNG images from my kinect depth and RGB data.
One way is to modify the code in image_view (which currently has provision to save a frame as JPG by right-clicking the mouse).
Is there a more direct way to do this? Or is there a provision already existing in ROS to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37611/generating-png-images-from-kinect-data/) by [rps2689](https://answers.ros.org/users/2743/rps2689/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi rps2689,

In the same stack as image_view there is another node called image_saver that saves image files without needing to click anything.

This node saves images in jpg format, so if you need them to be in PNG I guess that the fastest way is to modify the filename definition in */PATH_TO_ROS_STACKS/image_pipeline/image_view/src/nodes/image_saver.cpp*:

```
std::string filename = (g_format % g_count % "jpg").str();
```

for this other:

```
std::string filename = (g_format % g_count % "png").str();
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1